# regular expression javascript with punct,space and alnum

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello i need a regular expression for an empty string or a string with punct,alnum,and digit.

i try something like this but it doesn't work; what are my errors???

Thx for help

```
var regularExp=/(^$ || ^[[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]{80}$)/i;
```

Comment: what are trying to match? a sample case would help. what version of js are you aiming for? as pointed out by anubhava, you need to be specific (with version) when it comes to js regexes

Answer (score 5):

**Javascript regex cannot use POSIX character class as you're trying.** Unfortunately it doesn't also support PCRE classes.

You can probably use:

```
var regularExp = /^([a-z0-9\.,-\/#!$%' "^&*;:{}=_`~()-]{80})?$/ig;
```

Comment: !-/:-@[-`{-~ for all punctuation and symbols using unicode ranges https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters